# How to show differences between two duplicity backups?

Tags: backup, diff, duplicity

I want to be able to see the differences between two duplicity backups. I know there is the command `verify` but it only lists files which differ from the latest backup.
If I try `list-current-files` with different backup dates and then doing a `diff` it doesn't seem to work as expected.

So how can I get a list of changed and new files between two adjacent backups?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The route I personally take is to dump the list of files using `list-current-files`, as you suggested, but then use `grep` instead of `diff` to see the differences. An example of such is below:-

> duplicity list-current-files --time now "${DEST}" > /tmp/today
>   duplicity list-current-files --time 1D "${DEST}" > /tmp/yesterday
>   grep -Fxvf /tmp/{today,yesterday}

This would check the differences between the latest backup and yesterdays backup, but if you need to check two different dates you can replace `now` with any other accepted time.